# AngularJS filter not returning custom result

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new to AngularJS and decided to create little personal project with it. However I'm trying avoid displaying a value more than once. My model looks like so:

```
{
    "artist": "Tinchy Stryder",
    "album": "Catch 22",
    "filename": "01 - Take Off.mp3",
    "filepath": "Tinchy Stryder\/Catch 22\/01 - Take Off.mp3",
    "modified": 1388837746
},
{
    "artist": "Tinchy Stryder",
    "album": "Catch 22",
    "filename": "02 - I'm Landing.mp3",
    "filepath": "Tinchy Stryder\/Catch 22\/02 - I'm Landing.mp3",
    "modified": 1388837800
},
{
    "artist": "Tinchy Stryder",
    "album": "Catch 22",
    "filename": "03 - Take Me Back (feat. Taio Cruz).mp3",
    "filepath": "Tinchy Stryder\/Catch 22\/03 - Take Me Back (feat. Taio Cruz).mp3",
    "modified": 1388837861
}
```

I would like to only display the 'artist' once. I don't want to limit the ng-repeat to one item as I need to repeat through each filename. I have tried by creating this filter:

```
musicApp.filter('uniqueartist', function(){
    var keys = [];
    var output = "";

    return function(input, opt){

        if(keys.indexOf(input) === -1){
            output = input; 
            console.log(output)
            return output;
        }else{
            output = "";
            return output;
        }

        console.log(keys.indexOf(input));
        keys.push(input);

        return output;
    }
});
```

but it's still returning the artist name on every repeat. here is a snip of my html

```
<div class="row" data-ng-controller="SimpleController">
    <li ng-repeat="music in musics">
        <header><h4>{{music.artist | uniqueartist }}</h4></header>
        <p>{{music.filename}}</p>
        <a href="{{music.filepath}}">Listen</a>
    </li>
</div>
```

Any ideas why this isn't working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning too early, even before `keys.push(input)`.

Also, it is bad idea to keep state in filters, since they may be called arbitrary number of times. For example, if the array changes, the ng-repeat may run again in which case nothing gets displayed because the filter state doesn't get reset.

It may be best to modify your data model in the controller itself before it gets displayed. Perhaps add another property if you don't want to make destructive changes.

Comment: thanks for your response. you say i'm returning too early... but I return output; after pushing input into keys. Thanks for your help, I think I'll  modify the data model instead as you recommened that as best practice

Comment: @DBrowne Both your if and else have return statements. Neither the push nor the return after it have any effect. Anyhow, like I said, filters may not be the best use for this.